# Hi! am building up biometric attendance using fingerprint i have this problem where by the method only returns true only to my fingerprint

Tags: java

if(vrst.isVerified()){

```
        PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `regno`='"+regNo+"' AND `date`='"+signInDate+"'");
       ResultSet rs1 = pst.executeQuery();
         if(rs1.next()== false){
                  
            PreparedStatement pst2 = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `register`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `regno`, `sign_in_time`, `date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst2.setString(1, fngName);
            pst2.setString(2, lname);
            pst2.setString(3, regNo);
            pst2.setString(4, signInTime);
            pst2.setString(5, signInDate);

            pst2.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Sign in Successfully");       
        }else if(rs1.next() == true){
```

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record found. do you want to sign out");
PreparedStatement pst3 = c.prepareStatement("SELECT `regno`, `date` FROM register WHERE  `regno`='"+regNo+"' AND `date`='"+signInDate+"' AND ISNULL(`sign_out_time`)");

```
        ResultSet rs2 = pst3.executeQuery();
                  if(rs2.next()){
                      PreparedStatement pst4 = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE `register` SET `sign_out_time`= ?  WHERE `regno`='"+regNo+"' AND `date`='"+signInDate+"'");
                      pst4.setString(1, signOutTime);
                      pst4.executeUpdate();
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Sign Out Successfully");
                      
                  }else{
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Sign in again");
                      
                        PreparedStatement pst6 = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `register`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `regno`, `sign_in_time`, `date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                        pst6.setString(1, fngName);
                        pst6.setString(2, lname);
                        pst6.setString(3, regNo);
                        pst6.setString(4, signInTime);
                        pst6.setString(5, signInDate);

                        pst6.executeUpdate();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Sign in Successfully");

                  }
                      
              }
                 
              return; 
        }   
            
        }
                 // If it does not find any trace corresponding to the name, it indicates with a message
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There is no fingerprint that matches the search","\n Fingerprint Verification",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);      
       
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // If an error occurs, it indicates in the console
        System.err.println("Error identifying ."+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        dbcon.dscontrc();
    }
```

Comment: Hello Haruna, the title of your question should be direct and clear, something like (method should return false but return true).

Also, the formatting of your code block is incorrect, please be sure to add it clearly.

Comment: Ok, thanks of your observation Jalil...., its my first time being here